# Meteorjs after template rendered

Tags: meteor

I have written code to apply some jquery plugins to the selected fields after the template is rendered. But the below code is called for each option in the select field, but it should be called only once. I have other work around but I would like to understand rendered event of the template. Please help me in understanding this.

Comment: Ramu, please accept some answers on your previous questions. It is considered good practice here and will increase the chance that you get a good answer in the future.

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably talking about `Template.name.rendered`. Each time there is a reactive change in the template (for instance when you add a document to a collection referenced in your template, It has to be re-rendered to accomodate the new data.

If you don't want your select boxes re-rendered have a look at [preserve](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_preserve). It can be used to exclude elements from Meteor's reactivity